# Using java.awt.Point in model classes - bad coding style?

Tags: java, coding-style

I have an scenario with objects moving around on a coordinate system.
I thought of using java.awt.Point in my model classes, as it provides all the functionalty I need (location representation, translate, distance computation).

But using classes of java.awt in my model feels somehow wrong. 
But rewriting same funcionalty can't be the answer either.

So my question is: Is it okay to use such graphic related classes in model classes or is this bad style?
In case of bad style, what would be a good alternative approach?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you plan that one day to reuse the model on other platforms like Android then it is really not a good idea.

In general, I agree that java.awt classes shouldn't be part of the model of an application. I think I would create my own Point class and define the methods I need in there.

Comment: Yes, some platforms don't have AWT. But the counter argument is that Point is already written and tested code. It's in the AWT package but does not have any graphics specific code so it won't trigger GUI initialization.

Comment: Yes, there are pros and cons. I still keep my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use them, because adding GUI classes to our program has caused problem when running them in non-GUI environments (console), because they failed to initialize (I can't recall if it was AWT or Swing, though).

Answer (score 2):

I would roll my own duplicate, not because the Point class is part of the GUI, but because I prefer my model classes to contain only *immutable* values.