# text file with x y coordinates to empty Point2D[] array in Java

Tags: java, coordinates, grahams-scan

I want to read a file in Java and put the numbers from the file into the (x,y) coordinates of a Point2D[] array. How would I go about doing this?

my file looks like:

```
5 4
6 2
4 1
```

which are points (5,4) (6,2) (4,1).

Comment: Please post what you have tried and where you got stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have a `Point` class that looks like something like this (you could also use the [`java.awt.geom.Point2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html) class but it is [not advisable apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423606/using-java-awt-point-in-model-classes-bad-coding-style))  :

```
public class Point {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Point() {
        this(0, 0);
    }

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return this.x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return this.y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double distance(Point p2) {
        int dx = this.x - p2.x;
        int dy = this.y - p2.y;
        return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (other == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(other instanceof Point p2)) {
            return false;
        }
        return (this.x == p2.x) && (this.y == p2.y);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Point(%d, %d)", this.x, this.y);
    }
}
```

And a file called `points.txt` that you want to parse with the following contents:

```
5 4
6 2
4 1
```

You could use a **[`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)** to read the file line by line:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<Point> pointsList = new ArrayList<>();
        String fileName = "points.txt";
        try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Path.of(fileName))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] coordinates = line.split(" ");
                pointsList.add(new Point(
                    Integer.parseInt(coordinates[0]),
                    Integer.parseInt(coordinates[1])));
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("pointsList: %s%n", pointsList);
        Point[] pointsArray = pointsList.toArray(Point[]::new);
        System.out.printf("pointsArray: %s%n", Arrays.toString(pointsArray));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
pointsList: [Point(5, 4), Point(6, 2), Point(4, 1)]
pointsArray: [Point(5, 4), Point(6, 2), Point(4, 1)]
```